# how to use leaflet.shapefile plugin

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, shapefile, react-leaflet

how do we actually start using [leaflet.shapefile plugin from calvinmetcalf](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile/tree/gh-pages)? I ran `npm install shpjs --save`, but when I do something like `new L.Shapefile` it will show this error:

`leaflet__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4___default(...).Shapefile is not a constructor`

do I have to download the entire repo and drag it to my own code?